# PlacePicker.getPlace() and GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() is deprecated

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to develop an application based on google place API. When I try to use

```
 Place place=PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
```

or

```
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), MainActivity.this, 0);
```

there is an error showing getPlace() is deprecated.I have already tried

```
 getPlace(Context, Intent)
```

But it did not work.Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the new GoggleApiClient?

Comment: yes i m using new GoogleApiClient

Comment: Did you add  something as  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'  in your gradle dependencies?

Comment: "did not work" is a very vague description, please be more detailed, WHAT exactly is not working..

Comment: Yes i have addedcompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'

Comment: In getPlace(Context, Intent)   It says that Context and Intent -Expression expected

Comment: Google is tracking the interest in having a Place Picker widget here: (Android) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304810, (iOS) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760. Please fill the linked form with your use case and needs if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the [official android documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker#getPlace%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) the method

```
PlacePicker.getPlace(Intent, Context)
```

is deprecated. To get the place you should use:

```
Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(Context, Intent);
```

This being said, is the error persist, first thing you should do is check if you are using the latest dependencies (at the moment those are 10.0.1). I suggest to check your `build.gradle` file. It should look something like this:

```
[...]
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now, the really important bits here are the last 4 rows inside the `dependencies` block, those being:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
```

And the last line, it **HAS** to be the last line of the document:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```